# CURLFORM_STREAM pointer not being used by CURLOPT_READFUNCTION

Tags: stream, libcurl, mime, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a multipart MIME message with custom streaming (multiple binary files). To this end, I cannot get my `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` callback to use a pointer set by `CURLFORM_STREAM`.

So far as I can tell, [the `CURLFORM_STREAM` documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html#CURLFORMSTREAM) automatically calls the `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` pointer when it begins to stream data. This is not happening for me.

Here's my current code sample (I've been trying different configurations with no success). `CURLCODECHECK` and `CURLFORMCHECK` are macros that throw exceptions on an error. `streams` is a vector of my own `StreamData` structs.

```
        CURLCODECHECK(curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, 1L));
        CURLCODECHECK(curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, ::StreamReadFunction));

        for (auto iter = streams.begin(); iter != streams.end(); ++iter)
        {
            std::string const & name = iter->first;
            auto streamData = iter->second;

            CURLFORMCHECK(curl_formadd(&m_Post, &last,
                CURLFORM_COPYNAME, name.c_str(),
                CURLFORM_FILENAME, streamData->fileName.c_str(),
                CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, streamData->mimeType.c_str(),
                CURLFORM_STREAM, (void *) streamData.get(),
                CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH, streamData->size,
                CURLFORM_END));
        }
```

My `::StreamReadFunction` does get called, but unless I call `curl_easy_setopt()` with `CURLOPT_READDATA` set, it gets passed a null pointer for the fourth (void * userdata) argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `CURLOPT_HTTPPOST` is *not* a replacement for `CURLOPT_POST`. Both must be provided and `CURLOPT_POST` must be set *first*.

I moved my `curl_formadd()` call to the top of the function, and followed it with:

```
CURLCODECHECK(curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L));
CURLCODECHECK(curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, fieldSize));
CURLCODECHECK(curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, ::StreamReadFunction));
CURLCODECHECK(curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, m_Post));
CURLCODECHECK(curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L));
CURLCODECHECK(curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1L));
```

This then properly called my `::StreamReadFunction` with my stream pointer.

Note that `CURLOPT_POST` must be set *before* `CURLOPT_HTTPPOST` for the stream callback to use the proper pointer (placing `CURLOPT_POST` later will cause a null pointer to be passed in).